# Can Yudane method be used when making cookie dough?

Tags: baking

Can [Yudane method](https://www.bakewithpaws.com/2019/05/soft-sourdough-bread-with-yudane-method.html) be used to make cookies more chewy and moist? **Assuming the cookie dough is a recipe that is **made with some amount of milk**** and other enrichments like egg yolk, butter etc.

**EDIT**: I'm not referring to cookies that do not incorporate milk or other liquid into their dough.  This question only relates to those recipes that use a small amount of liquid, usually milk, that can be used for the scalding process.

Comment: That sounds like a slightly chaotic idea? The principles of bread and cookies are pretty much opposite, from preparation over gluten development to expected texture… can you elaborate, please, what your line of thinking was and what gave you the idea?

Comment: @Stephie from what i've read, its supposed to make the bread more soft and moist for longer period.  mixing the hot water with flour gelatinized the starches enabling them to take in more water, and I think it also denatures the gluten.  cookies are also made with flour so why wouldn't the effects of Yudane also carry over to that as well.  Of course I'm referring to cookie recipes that use a small amount of milk that can be used for the scalding process, not recipes that don't have a liquid component.

Comment: Can’t phrase it properly, but my baking instinct says “no way”.

Answer (score 1):

Today I learned that you apparently **can** use tangzhong in extra soft cookies:

King Arthur Flour published their [Cookie of the Year 2024](https://www.kingarthurbaking.com/recipes/supersized-super-soft-chocolate-chip-cookies-recipe) which does so and based on the ratings, it works.

As yudane is close enough to tangzhong, it should work as well. If you are planning to modify your own recipe, you’ll possibly need a few tries either way.

So good luck and feel free to self answer with more practical advice.

Answer (score -2):

That's a good idea but am afraid that is possible can their ingredients are different. Water can't be used to replace air but they are both important.